# How to add all items at index to new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently trying to re-sort a list I got from parsing a website.

I have tried everything but I don't think I found the best solution to my problem.

Let's say we have the following list:

```
my_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

What I am trying to convert it to:

```
new_list = [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

I came up with the following loop:

```
result = [[], [], []]

for sublist in my_list:
    for i in range(0, len(sublist)):
        result[i].append(sublist[i])
print(result)
# output: [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

My method is not the best I assume and I am searching for the most **pythonic** way to do it if you know what I'm saying.

Comment: use zip https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: `list(zip(my_list[0], my_list[1]))`

Comment: I recommend reading the Python tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Do you want `[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]` as `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]` or `[[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]]` ?

Comment: @Boris you even simpler: `list(zip(*my_list))` (though the output will be `tuple`s instead of `list`s)

Comment: I would go with @pault's recommendation so you don't run into index errors and it works if there are more than two sublists.

Comment: Thank you guys I'm gonna mark this one as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python builtin function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is your friend here.

From the official documentation, it

> returns an iterator of tuples, where the *i*-th tuple contains the *i*-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

What that means is that given two lists, `zip(list1, list2)` will pair `list1[0]` with `list2[0]`, `list1[1]` with `list2[1]`, and so on.

In your case, the lists you want to zip together are inside another list, `my_list`, so you can unpack it with `*my_list`. Since `zip()` returns an iterator, you want to create a list out of the return value of `zip()`. Final solution:

```
new_list = list(zip(*my_list))
```

Comment: Output will be: [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]. The questioner want to get lists instead of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code which exactly does what you want. You should use `map` after `zip` to convert tuples to lists.

**Code:**

```
my_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
my_new_list = list(map(list, zip(my_list[0], my_list[1])))
print(my_new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

Comment: equivalent list comp: `my_new_list = [list(t) for t in zip(my_list[0], my_list[1])]`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't see any advantage of list comp. I think both solutions are proper. :)

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to mention it for OP's sake :)